# How to generate string_3 from the difference between string_1 and string_2?

Tags: ruby, string

I have 2 strings:

```
string_1 = "abcdefg"

string_2 = "adg"
```

How to generate `string_3` from the difference between `string_1` and `string_2`?

```
string_3 = "bcef"
```

Comment: What should be `string_3` be if `string_1 = "abgdegdfg"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-delete) is provided for precisely this purpose. I'm surprised it was suggested earlier. Perhaps some Rubiests think this method is for deleting substrings, which is not correct.

```
string_1 = "abacdefg"
string_2 = "adg"

string_1.delete(string_2)
  #=> "bcef"
```

Note that I added an `"a"` to `string_1` to show that both `"a"`'s are deleted.

Comment: I just noticed that @Gagan edited his answer to include mine before I posted my answer. As he beat me by only 6 seconds, I'll leave my answer. :-).

Comment: no worries, 6 sec doesn't matter right solution matter, even though I beat you with 6 sec still your answer accepted ;) :D 1+

Answer (score 3):

Try: **[String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-tr)**

```
 > string_3 = string_1.tr(string_2, '')
 #=> "bcef"
```

**OR**

**[String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-delete)**

```
 > string_3 = string_1.delete(string_2)
 #=> "bcef"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

```
string_1 = "abcdefg".split("") => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
string_2 = "adg".split("") => ["a", "d", "g"]
string_3 = string_1 - string_2 => ["b", "c", "e", "f"]
string_3 = string_3.join() => ["bcef"]
```

I think this is what you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use `#chars` instead `#split` => `"abcdefg".chars => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the data in your example but might be insufficient for more complicated data.

```
string_1 = "abcdefg"
string_2 = "adg"

(string_1.chars - string_2.chars).join
 => "bcef"
```

on one line

```
("abcdefg".chars - "adg".chars).join
 => "bcef"
```

Answer (score 0):

@codesponge have provided the cleanest answer, but let me post it for curiosity.

```
string_1.chars.keep_if {|e| !string_2.include? e }.join
#=> "bcef"
```

`drop_while`, `take_while` and other similar methods also could be used.

Comment: There are several weaknesses with this answer. 1) Why convert a string to an array, operate on it and then convert back to a string, when there are several more efficient ways to do this with `String` methods alone, such as `delete`, `tr` and `gsub`? 2) `Array#keep_if` (aka `select!`) mutates `string_1`, which is not part of the spec. 3) You can avoid the negation  in the block (and the mutation) by using `reject`. 4) traversing `string_2` for each character in `string_1` is very inefficient. 5) use `each_char` rather than `chars` to avoid the creation of a temporary array.